# If I subscribe to a PE in my LWC, is it best practice to unsubscribe?

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-event, subscriber

I have a PE listener in my LWC and I am not sure if I should always call disconnectedCallback() after I subscribe or if this is immediately disconnecting the just connected subscriber. When does disconnectedCallback() run? If I don't disconnect, am I susceptible to memory leaks?

```
connectedCallback() {
  const messageCallback = (response) => {...};

  // Subscribe to the platform event
  subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then((response) => {
    this.subscription = response;
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error subscribing to event", JSON.stringify(error));
  });

  onError((error) => {
    console.error("Received error from server:", JSON.stringify(error));
  });
} 

disconnectedCallback() {
  this.unsubscribe();
}

unsubscribe() {
  if (this.subscription) {
    unsubscribe(this.subscription, (response) => {
      console.log("Unsubscribed from channel", JSON.stringify(response));
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should `unsubscribe` during `disconnectedCallback`. There are two reasons for this. First, as you surmise, there is an associated client-side memory leak if you don't. Second, PE has daily limits on deliveries, and so your now-disconnected, non-garbage-collected component will continue to eat up additional PE allocations until it eventually times out.

`disconnectedCallback` is called when the LWC is removed from the DOM and no longer visible. You never directly call this method. In a component, this may be caused by `if:true`, `if:false`, `lwc:if`, `lwc:elseif`, or `lwc:else` changing the connected status for the component. In the LWC, components may be left in a cache until memory pressure causes the component to be permanently disconnected, at which point `disconnectedCallback` will be called.